# Update a table with data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     a       abc
2     b       def
3     c       adf
```

Table 2:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
```

In oracle SQL, how do I run an **sql update** query that can update Table 1 with Table 2's `name` and `desc` using the same `id`? So the end result I would get is

Table 1:

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
3     c       adf
```

Question is taken from [update one table with data from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/sql-update-query-with-data-from-another-table), but specifically for oracle SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql update query with data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036918/sql-update-query-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Yeah.  And this probably isn't the best example since "desc" is a reserved word, but oh well.

Answer (score 638, accepted):

This is called a correlated update

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT t2.name, t2.desc
                         FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id )
```

Assuming the join results in a key-preserved view, you could also

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.id, 
               t1.name name1,
               t1.desc desc1,
               t2.name name2,
               t2.desc desc2
          FROM table1 t1,
               table2 t2
         WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
   SET name1 = name2,
       desc1 = desc2
```

Comment: In your first code example: Is the outer WHERE-clause necessary for correct results? Or do you use it only to speed up the query?

Comment: @totoro - In the first example, the `WHERE EXISTS` prevents you from updating a row in `t1` if there is no matching row in `t2`.  Without it, every row in `t1` will be updated and the values will be set to `NULL` if there is no matching row in `t2`.  That is generally not what you want to happen so the `WHERE EXISTS` is generally needed.

Comment: It's worth adding that the `SELECT ... FROM t2` **must** result in a unique row. This means that you have to select on all the fields which comprise a unique key -- a non-unique primary key is not sufficient. Without uniqueness, you are reduced to something like [@PaulKarr's loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17333889/1204258) -- and if there is not a unique correlation, then more than one target row may be updated for each source row.

Comment: Would the WHERE EXISTS be better as WHERE t1.id IN (select id from t2) so you get a hash join instead of an EXISTS query on every row?

Comment: @NathanSpears - It depends.  Recent versions of Oracle are pretty good at producing the optimal plan whether you're using `IN` or `EXISTS`.  If there is a difference, if you expect that the inline query is generally going to return a relatively large fraction of the rows in the target table, an `EXISTS` would generally be more efficient, an `IN` would generally be more efficient if you expect to return a relatively small fraction of the rows in the target table.  Of course "small" and "large" are relative terms so the only real answer is to benchmark and see.

Comment: Explanation on key-preserved requirement for updatable joins: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486

Comment: Thank you for sharing this wonderful answer. Just want to ask, i have a similar case and when using the above method(Correlated update) getting message that "Single-row subquery returns mre than one row". Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: @RachitSharma - That means that your subquery (the query from `table2`) is returning multiple rows for one or more `table1` values and Oracle doesn't know which one you want to use.  Normally, that means that you need to refine the subquery so that it returns a single distinct row.

Comment: wrong answer performance wise, there is `MERGE` command specifically for that

Comment: My concern about the "where exists" query is that it requires two accesses to table2.

Comment: Using merge is definitely better than using "update ... where exists ...", except when you want to update the field used to join the two tables. Merge does not work in this case, and you have to use this "update" solution.

Answer (score 249):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING
(
-- For more complicated queries you can use WITH clause here
SELECT * FROM table2
)t2
ON(t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
t1.name = t2.name,
t1.desc = t2.desc;
```

Comment: Very fast indeed, 1159477 rows merged in 15,5s

Comment: I hope everybody visiting this question after 2015 notices this answer. Note that this also works if `table1` and `table2` are the same table, just take care of the `ON`-part and the `WHERE`-clause for the `SELECT`-statement of `table2`!

Comment: I find that every time I need to do another merge I keep coming back to this answer for inspiration. I might print it out and frame it on my wall

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ID, FIELD1, FIELD1 FROM table2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL

Comment: t1.name = CASE WHEN t2.name is NULL THEN t1.name ELSE t2.name END -- Keeps system from Nulling out values when no value exists in t2.

Comment: solution with MERGE INTO is my favourite, because it's easy to use with complex subselect instead of simple table (t2 may be joined tables with conditions, aggegated...). The code remains readable and processing is quick.

Comment: Worked for me in old Oracle 10g2.

Comment: No idea if MERGE is a non-standard Oracle invention, but it does the job in a way that is much less abstract than the methods trying to force UPDATE do the job

Comment: This is very very fast compared with other queries. Could you please improve the answer with the WITH clause? Thanks!

Comment: What would cause this error to throw when running the MERGE query - "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables", as my source table/query has multiple key ids. I use distinct select in my inner query or for the table2 query although.
```merge into sa.table1 t1
using (select distinct userid, keylinkflag from table2)src
on (t1.userid = src.userid)
when matched 
   then update 
        set t1.keylinkflag = src.keylinkflag, t1.manual_linking_flag = 1, t1.link = null
WHERE t1.keylinkflag is null;
```

Comment: I solved this. This was due to the data dupes and i had to do a group by and add more filters to pick only one for each combo.

Answer (score 27):

try

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 SET
T1.name = (SELECT T2.name FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id),
T1.desc = (SELECT T2.desc FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id)
WHERE T1.id IN (SELECT T2.id FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id);
```

Comment: The downside of this is that the SELECT statement is repeated 3 times. In complex examples that can be a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 15):

```
Update table set column = (select...)
```

never worked for me since set only expects 1 value - SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

here's the solution:

```
BEGIN
For i in (select id, name, desc from table1) 
LOOP
Update table2 set name = i.name, desc = i.desc where id = i.id;
END LOOP;
END;
```

That's how exactly you run it on SQLDeveloper worksheet. They say it's slow but that's the only solution that worked for me on this case.

Comment: can somebody please explain why this deserves a -2 on reputation? LOL.

Comment: I didn't down rate, but it isn't a good solution. Firstly: if the subselect was returning multiple values, then the for loop will be overwriting the name on table2 multiple times for some/all records (not clean). Secondly: there is no order by clause so this will occur in an unpredictable manner (i.e. last value in unordered data wins). Thirdly: It will be much slower. Assuming the outcome of the for loop was intended, the original subselect could have been rewritten in some controlled way to return only 1 value for each record... simplest contrived way would be (select min(name)...)

Comment: If you get multiple values in your subquery, you might rethink the query and use DISTINCT or GROUP BY with MIN, MAX.  Just an idea.

Comment: Long story short: if you can at all avoid it, never ever EVER use any kind of LOOP in a T-SQL statement.  Personally, if it wasn't for the 0.001% of the time where there's no other solution, I don't even think it should even be an available function in T-SQL.  T-SQL is designed to be set-based, so it works on entire sets of data as a whole; it should NOT be used to work on data line-by-line.

Comment: This is terribly slow and inefficient. You didn't even filter table1! If table1 has 150 million records in it and table2 only has 10, you'lle cycle 150 million times for no reason at all. And even if you did filter it, it's still slow as hell for any large dataset. Use a MERGE statement instead.

Answer (score 10):

Here seems to be an even better answer with 'in' clause that allows for **multiple keys for the join**:

```
update fp_active set STATE='E', 
   LAST_DATE_MAJ = sysdate where (client,code) in (select (client,code) from fp_detail
  where valid = 1) ...
```

The full example is here:
[http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/how-to-update-from-two-tables-195893.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130127142113/http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/how-to-update-from-two-tables-195893.html) - from web archive since link was dead.

The beef is in having the columns that you want to use as the key in parentheses in the where clause before 'in' and have the select statement with the same column names in parentheses.
where (**column1,column2**) in ( *select (**column1,column2**) from table where "the set I want"* );

Comment: Link is expired. (`404`)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Database 23c has added [direct joins for `update` and `delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nfcoa/application-development.html#GUID-27BEDD0F-AF38-43C0-8F44-363C16C68184):

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int, c2 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int, c2 int
);

insert into t1 values ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2 );
insert into t2 values ( 1, 42 );

select * from t1;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2

update t1
set    t1.c2 = t2.c2
from   t2
where  t1.c1 = t2.c1;

select * from t1;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1         42
         2          2

delete t1
from   t2
where  t1.c1 = t2.c1;

select * from t1;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         2          2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BEGIN
For i in (select id, name, desc from table2) 
LOOP
Update table1 set name = i.name, desc = i.desc where id = i.id and (name is null or desc is null);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score -2):

If your table t1 and it's backup t2 have many columns, here's a compact way to do it.

In addition, my related problem was that only some of the columns were modified and many rows had no edits to these columns, so I wanted to leave those alone - basically restore a subset of columns from a backup of the entire table.  If you want to just restore all rows, skip the where clause.

Of course the simpler way would be to delete and insert as select, but in my case I needed a solution with just updates.

The trick is that when you do select * from a pair of tables with duplicate column names, the 2nd one will get named _1.  So here's what I came up with:

```
  update (
    select * from t1 join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    where id in (
      select id from (
        select id, col1, col2, ... from t2
        minus select id, col1, col2, ... from t1
      )
    )
  ) set col1=col1_1, col2=col2_1, ...
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Oracle 11g.  Can you create a working example of this method?