# Update multiple rows in a table from another table when condition exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgis

I have two tables.

**Table1** contains companies whose locations are georeferenced with lat/lng coordinates in a column called `the_geom`

**Table2** also contain the same companies from **Table1**, not georeferenced, along with hundreds of other companies whose addresses are georeferenced.

All I need to do is insert `the_geom` lat/lng values from **Table1** companies into their corresponding entries in **Table 2**.  The common denominator on which these inserts can be based on is the `address` column.

Simple question, I am sure, but I rarely use SQL.

Comment: you dont insert rows here, you update.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming that by

> insert "the_geom" lat/lng values

you actually mean to **`UPDATE`** existing rows in `table2`:

```sql
UPDATE table2 t2
SET    the_geom = t1.the_geom
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  t2.address = t1.address
AND    t2.the_geom IS DISTINCT FROM t1.the_geom;  -- avoid empty updates
```

Related answer:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Also assuming that the `address` column has `UNIQUE` values.
[Details for `UPDATE` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: Yeap, exactly what I meant, this did the trick. Thanks Erwin.

Comment: @LP13: Yes. If you follow the link to the manual I provided, you see `UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]` in the "Synopsis" right at the top. (Syntax for some other RDBMS differs, see "Compatibility" at the bottom of the same page.)

Comment: UPDATE table2
SET the_geom = t1.the_geom
FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE  t2.address = t1.address
AND    t2.the_geom IS DISTINCT FROM t1.the_geom;

Comment: @AMRESHPANDEY: The additional join to `table2` is redundant. (Or what are you trying to tell us?)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter How shall I do this in Oracle?

Comment: @coderzzz18: Oracle has no `FROM` clause for `UPDATE` . See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.10 There are a couple of alternatives (not as straight forward IMO) See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#i2067715 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7030699/939860

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter , I achieved through Merge command and when matched I updated. I hope that helps to others like me :)

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, but when I tried the solutions mentioned above, I got an error like

*Incorrect syntax near 't2'*

The code that worked for me is:

```
UPDATE table2
SET the_geom = t1.the_geom
FROM table1 as t1
WHERE table2.address = t1.address AND table2.the_geom <> t1.the_geom
```

I know that my answer is 5 years late, but I hope this will help someone like me, who couldn't find this solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you are a mysql user(like me) and if the above script is not working, here is the mysql equivalent.

```
UPDATE table2 t2, table1 t1
SET    the_geom = t1.the_geom
WHERE  t2.address = t1.address
AND    t2.the_geom <> t1.the_geom; -- avoid empty updates
```

All credits to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- e.g. scenario for demo
--Creating a rollup monthly customer invoice 
--For customers that buy individual items on credit.

--What I am demonstrating here is that you can update 
--a table based on some joins etc.. from a complex query

WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
         c.customerId  --get cusomers
        ,sum(o.Cost) as cost --sum all the individual orders 
    FROM customers c
    LEFT JOIN orders o on c.orderId = o.orderId
    where 1=1
    AND orderId in (
         115254
        ,115270
        ,115285
        ,115291
        ,115319
        ,115324
        ,115325
    )
    group by orderId
)

--updating based on the sum of all orders by customer
UPDATE invoice 
SET Customer_Invoice_Amount = cte.cost
FROM  cte
WHERE invoice.orderId = cte.orderId
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how the SQL in your answer is [even remotely] related to the posted question. By the way, answers that contain code only are generally considered poor quality. Ususally it is a good idea to add some explanation as to how the code in your answer solves the problem described in the posted question.