# How to insert missing rows and update exists in 10M table

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, import

*Q: How to insert missing rows and update exists from data source in a relatively short time?*

Exists rarely updated Postgre table and not powerful server (1Gb ram for apache2 and middle CPU). There are **10 M** records. Some records can be updated some records can be added.

Data source is big CSV file produced by php script.

**Table structure**:

```
id (auto inc.)
week_number (1-54)
audience_id (int)
channel_id (int)
is_weekend (char, Y or N)
start_time (hours, offset in minutes after midnight)
rating (numberic. In fact main value)
```

**Rating** field is determined by next fields set: **week_number**, **audience_id**, **channel_id**, **is_weekend** and **start_time** Let's call it "*complex_key*" in a future.

What I did (php server side):

- loop exists db data via foreach (batch select) and store pairs "*complex_key*" => *rating* in a redis cache. Next compare with *csv* row by row and prepare new set of data. **Optimisation**: Unset everything I can, optimize arrays e.t.c Result: **Failed**. Memory limit. (php side, not redis)
- Use [Pg copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) to create temp table. The idea was to use DB engine to compare tables and to make needed changes. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869584/update-multiple-rows-in-a-table-from-another-table-when-condition-exists). Ofc I added additional field which contained "*complex_key*" hash and mark it as index. Result: working too slow if we compare 1M+ tables.

Comment: If you use postgres 9.5+ then you should take a look at UPSERT concept ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html))

Comment: `MERGE` (aka UPSERT) is the way to go.  Did you perform any `ANALYZE` between populating your temp table and updating the target table?  This can have a big effect on efficiency.

Comment: I have 9.0, without ability to upgrade. So upsert and merge not working here.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to create a SQL file of updates and inserts in a transaction block (BEGIN...COMMIT). Load the file via command line psql. This method won't reduce fetch/computation time, but will create a dramatic increase in speed during update.