# update query result not reflecting in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `test1` and `test2`. What I need is, I would like to update one column in the table `test2` with data from the table `test1`. My query is

```
 UPDATE test2 t2 
    SET t2.name = (SELECT t1.name 
                     FROM test1 t1 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.mob)
  WHERE t2.mob IN (SELECT t1.id 
                     FROM test1 t1 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.mob)
```

It's showing `3 Rows updated` , But It's not reflecting in my table. My [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-with-data-from-another-table). Is there any issue in my query. Or what should I do alternately.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` part in your query is absolutely unnecessary because it always evaluates to `TRUE`. So the correct one to update all rows in `t2` is:

```
UPDATE test2 t2 
 SET t2.name = (SELECT t1.name 
                 FROM test1 t1 
                WHERE t1.id = t2.mob)
```

Also in PL/SQL Developer transactions are not commited automatically by default. You have to manually commit it by pressing that green arrow on the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It wold be easier to use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement:

```
/* test tables */

SQL> create table test1(id1, name1) as
  2    select level
  3         , dbms_random.string('l', 7)
  4    from dual
  5    connect by level <= 5;
Table created

SQL> create table test2(id1, name1) as
  2    select level
  3         , cast(null as varchar2(11))
  4    from dual
  5    connect by level <= 5;
Table created
```

Tables' contents:

```
SQL> column name1 format a10;
SQL> select * from test1;

       ID1 NAME1
---------- ----------
         1 ouegwac
         2 bptytsz
         3 xwpnuqi
         4 jrbxeza
         5 hlckwvk

SQL> select * from test2;

       ID1 NAME1
---------- ----------
         1 NULL
         2 NULL
         3 NULL
         4 NULL
         5 NULL
```

Update `test2.name1` column with data from `test1.name1` column:

```
SQL> merge into test2 t
  2  using test1 q
  3     on (q.id1 = t.id1)
  4  when matched then
  5    update set t.name1 = q.name1
  6  ;

5 rows merged

SQL> select * from test2;

       ID1 NAME1
---------- ----------
         1 ouegwac
         2 bptytsz
         3 xwpnuqi
         4 jrbxeza
         5 hlckwvk
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT test2.name as t2, test1.name as t1
 FROM test2
 INNER JOIN test1
 ON test2.MOB= test1.ID

) t
SET t.t2= t.t1
```