# UPDATE with OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I've searched and searched and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Without going into detail of what exactly is in these tables (they are pretty basic `varchar` columns, nothing out of the ordinary), why does this keep giving me the 'SQL command not properly ended' error.

The first `NVL` is so I can set the `SPID_NAME` to `'Unknown'` if there is no match between `SN1.SUB_GRP_NAME` and `L1.SUB_GRP_NAME`.

The second `NVL` is used because sometimes `L1.SUB_GRP_NAME` is `NULL`, and I change it to `'9999'`.

I'm using PLSQL/Oracle Developer 3.1.07.

```
update L1
SET L1.SPID_NAME = NVL(SUB_GRP_TO_NAME.SPID_NAME, 'Unknown')
from ACME_NORMAL L1
left outer join SUB_GRP_TO_NAME SN1
on SN1.SUB_GRP_NAME = NVL(L1.SUB_GRP_NAME,'9999');
```

Comment: When you alias SUB_GRP_TO_NAME as SN1 you should remember to use the alias everywhere; including in `NVL (SUB_GRP_TO_NAME.SPID_NAME, 'Unknown')
` to make it `NVL(SN1.SPID_NAME, 'Unknown')`

Comment: It would be one of the many things I've tried to see if it made any difference. But  alas , it didn't.

Comment: Are you delimiting your strings with the single quote character (ie ') or a back-tick character (ie `). It needs to be single quote, and your code appears to be using back-tick.

Comment: Sorry guys, realised what the problem was. I'm using the wrong UPDATE syntax for PLSQL.

Comment: Please check this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-with-data-from-another-table

Comment: If you found your solution, please add it as an answer and accept it to remove this question from the open questions list.