# performing an update query with a select subquery returning ora-01427 error

Tags: oracle, subquery

I need to update a column in one table with the results from a select sub-query (and they should ultimately be different). But When I do this, I get the 'ORA-01427: single row sub-query returns more than one row query' error.

Can you please take a look and see what it is that I am overlooking? (I could just be overlooking something simple for all I know)

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY ans
SET ANS.NBR_RETURNS = (  
    SELECT SUM(RQ.RETURN_QTY)
    FROM RETURN_QTY RQ JOIN AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY ANS ON RQ.LOC_ID = ANS.LOC_ID
    WHERE RQ.FSCL_YR_NUM       = ans.FSCL_YR_NUM
    AND RQ.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM =
      ans.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
    GROUP BY ANS.LOC_ID,
      ans.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM,
      ANS.FSCL_YR_NUM
        );
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using the following example
`UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT t2.name, t2.desc
                         FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id )`
provided by the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your inner query is not well correlated to the table that you're trying to update. Please look here [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-with-data-from-another-table). You should add some kind of a `where` condition that ties the rows you're trying to update with the values calculated by the inner statement.

Comment: Alright.  Thank you.  I couldn't find what I needed from searches on my end (maybe I glanced over it).  and I didn't have a basis to go by.  Thanks.