# Oracle: Using CTE with update clause

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Can I make an update using common table expression in oracle database?

I am getting error `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` when I am trying this:

```
with average as (SELECT avg(salary) FROM instructor)
update instructor
               set salary = case
                   when salary <= average then salary * 1.05 
                   else salary * 1.03                                     
               end
```

Comment: I do not have much experience with Oracle database, but I think you're getting an error because you want to use a CTE (that returns results in the form of a table) inside an update. Why don't you just store the result of `SELECT avg(salary) FROM instructor` into a variable and use it in the UPDATE? I think it's the simplest way to do what you want..

Comment: Okay I will do that. But i have a question can we use with and update clause together?

Comment: As I said, a [CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) returns results in the form of a table, and then you can use it through JOINs with other tables, or use in other ways (but not in the way you're using it) in order to have the results you want. So, to answer your question: No, you cannot use a CTE (it's not named 'with') in that way like yours.

Comment: It is syntactically incorrect. Yes, you can use WITH clause in an update statement, See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `average salary` just a *scalar value* you can do

```
update instructor
   set salary = case
       when salary <= (select avg(t.salary) from instructor t) then salary * 1.05 
       else salary * 1.03                                     
   end
```

In that case Oracle first *compute the average* (say `1234.4567`) and then perform the *update*.

Comment: But the above query is valid right? So we can use 'with' clause with 'update' right?

Comment: @shashankgaurav In this case you don't need a CTE to compute the average since it's calculated inside CASE WHEN statement.

Comment: @alberto I was my talking about my query.

Comment: @shashankgaurav Indeed, you cannot use CTE and UPDATE all together like in your query. That's why Dmitry slightly modified your query.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I do something like this in oracle database?

Well, it is not about whether you could do it or not. It is about whether you need to do it or not. In your query I don't see any filter criteria. You want to update all the rows? I don't see a need of **CTE** in your case.

When do you need a **CTE**, i.e. a with clause as a sub-query factoring method whenever you have a scenario where the sub-query is executed multiple times. You use a WITH clause to make sure the subquery is executed once, and the resultset is stored as a temp table.

Yes, you could use **WITH** clause for an **UPDATE** statement.

For example,

```
UPDATE TABLE t
SET t.column1, t.column2 = (SELECT column1, column2 FROM 
                                       (
                                        WITH cte AS(
                                   SELECT ... FROM another_table
                                                 )
                                         SELECT * FROM cte
                                        )
```

You could use a **MERGE** statement **USING** the **WITH** clause.

For example,

```
SQL> MERGE INTO emp e USING
  2  (WITH average AS
  3    (SELECT deptno, AVG(sal) avg_sal FROM emp group by deptno)
  4  SELECT * FROM average
  5  ) u
  6  ON (e.deptno = u.deptno)
  7  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  8  UPDATE SET e.sal      =
  9    CASE
 10      WHEN e.sal <= u.avg_sal
 11      THEN e.sal * 1.05
 12      ELSE e.sal * 1.03
 13    END
 14  /

14 rows merged.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basing on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031405/603516) on correlated update of key-preserved view, here is another possible option to use CTE with update in Oracle SQL avoiding duplication of where clause:

```
update (
    with cte as (select avg(salary) average_salary from instructor)
    select id, salary, cte.average_salary from instructor cross join cte
    where <some_condition>
)
set salary = case
    when salary <= average_salary/2 then salary * 1.1 
    when salary <= average_salary then salary * 1.05 
    else salary * 1.03                                     
end
```

In case of self-join this can be simplified to CTE-less version:

```
update (
    select id, salary, (select avg(salary) from instructor) average_salary 
    from instructor
    where <some_condition>
)
set salary = case
    when salary <= average_salary/2 then salary * 1.1 
    when salary <= average_salary then salary * 1.05 
    else salary * 1.03                                     
end
```

Comment: Here is more on "key preserved" thing: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38728/oracle-non-key-preserved-table-should-be