# CTE and table update in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a lot of complicated logic I want to run before I finally store the result by updating a column in a table. I am getting an error and have been able to get it down to:

```
with my_cte as
(
  select x,ix from y
)
update z
set mycol = (select x from my_cte where z.ix = my_cte.ix)
```

This however gives the error:

```
Error at line 4:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
set mycol = (select x from my_cte where z.ix = my_cte.ix)
```

Does this simply mean CTEs cannot be used with updates since the following query works fine:

```
update z
set mycol = (select x from y where y.ix = my_cte.ix)
```

Using version 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Edit:

*After tackling this problem for a while the only way to get a reasonable performance was to use the MERGE clause instead (Still using CTEs as in the answers below).*

```
merge into z using (
  with my_cte as (
    select x,ix from y
  )
)
on (
  my_cte.ix = z.ix 
)
when matched then
update set mycol = my_cte.x
```

Comment: CTE can still be used as update subquery like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534514/603516

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Oracle, the CTE is part of the `SELECT` not the `UPDATE`:

```
update z
    set mycol = (
          with my_cte as (
             select x, ix
             from y
          )
          select x from my_cte where z.ix = my_cte.ix
         );
```

Comment: With this approach, how would you update multiple columns simultaneously? Wouldn't you have to run the same CTE multiple times?

Comment: @VinceI . . . No.  You can update multiple columns at once with a single subquery in Oracle.

Comment: could you please demonstrate how that would be accomplished using an example similar to above?

Comment: @VinceI . . . If you have a question, it should be asked as a *question*, not a *comment*.

Comment: Works only for single column :-( `update t SET (mycol, mycol_2) = (WITH my_cte AS (...) select x,y ...)` fails with `ORA-01767: UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery`

Answer (score 3):

If z.ix - is primary kay and y.ix - is foreign key to z.ix you may write

```
update (select y.x, z.mycol
             from y, z 
           where y.ix = x.ix)
    set mycol = x;
```