# Oracle 10 how to update a table as a sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with identical columns `ID`, `A`, `B`, `C`.

I need to ADD to `TableX` the values from `TableY` for the corresponding `ID`'s. I know how to do this for a SINGLE update as follows:

```
update TableX x
set x.A= x.A +
    (select y.A
    from TableY y
    where x.id= y.id)
where exists (select y.id
    from TableY y
    where x.id = Y.id).
```

But how to modify this statement so that I can update multiple columns as sums?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update TableX x
set (x.A, x.B, x.C) = (select y.A + x.A,
                              y.B + x.B,
                              y.C + x.C
                       from TableY y 
                       where x.id= y.id)
where exists (
  select y.id 
  from TableY y 
  where x.id = Y.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
merge into tableX x
using (select * from tableY) y
on (x.id = y.id)
when matched then update set
  x.a = x.a + y.a, x.b = x.b + y.b, x.c = x.c + y.c;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df0923/1)</sup>

You could use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm), especially if you want also insert non existing rows.

Comment: I have never used Merge, but I will definitely experiment with it. Thanks.

Comment: If you are interested in further reading about `merge` statement then I advise this old, good article ["the merge statement in oracle 9i"](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=203) for start and [this thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5318183934935) from _Ask Tom_ site. If you are working with Oracle it's definitely something you should know.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this the following way in Teradata:

```
Update X
From TableX X,
(Select A,B,C From TableY Where id in (select id from TableX group by 1)) S
set
A=A+S.A
,B=B+S.B
,C=C+S.C
where exists (select y.id
from TableY y
where x.id = Y.id)
```

Comment: You might be able to do that in Teradata, but you can't do that in Oracle (which is what this question is about)