# How to add corresponding list of values to SQL parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How do I make the query like this?

```
UPDATE DUA_DATA_FIL_AUD
SET REV       = :rev,
  SYS_UPDT_TS = :now
WHERE DUA_DATA_FIL_ID = 283
AND REV = 2524;
```

And so on for all the next 13 records and update all the corresponding columns?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a result of dynamic update queries using a select form the table you want to apply the updates on it's result set.

This shall create you a sort of script that you can copy and run in your command window to update the desired lines.

Hope this addresses what you really want :

```
    SELECT 'UPDATE DUA_DATA_FIL_AUD SET REV = :rev, SYS_UPDT_TS = :now WHERE 
DUA_DATA_FIL_ID =' || DUA_DATA_FIL_ID || 'AND REV =' || MAX(REV) || ';/'
    FROM DUA_DATA_FIL_AUD GROUP BY DUA_DATA_FIL_ID,REV
```