# How to update a table's column value from a different table's same column values?

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

template table.(`templ_id` and `obj_id` is primary key)

```
templ_id    obj_id

TP000002    PE554959
TP000003    PE555867
TP000006    PE555102
TP000009    PE554994
TP000009    PE554956
TP000009    PE555176
TP000009    PE555598
TP000009    PE555256
TP000010    PE555297
TP000010    PE555286
```

Business table.(`bsn_no` is primary key)

```
bsn_no    obj_id     templ_id
1         PE554959   null
2         PE555867   null
3         PE555102   null
4         PE554994   null
5         PE554956   null
6         PE555176   null
7         PE555598   null
8         PE555256   null
9         PE555297   null
10        PE555286   null
```

I want to update business tables `templ_id` from template table's `templ_id` based on the `obj_id` using a single update query.

Comment: Depend on what DBMS are you using

Comment: Oracle sql developer

Comment: Then look at this solution for Oracle specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table

Comment: it is not the similar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE BusinessTable
SET BusinessTable.templ_id = (SELECT TemplateTable.templ_id
                               FROM TemplateTable
                               WHERE BusinessTable.obj_id = TemplateTable.obj.id )
```

IF the IDs are the same you can group the subquery:

```
UPDATE BusinessTable
SET BusinessTable.templ_id = (SELECT TemplateTable.templ_id
                               FROM TemplateTable
                               WHERE BusinessTable.obj_id = TemplateTable.obj.id 
                               GROUP BY Template.templ_id
                               )
```

Comment: i have tried with this code. but it has thrown the below error
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: That is what he was talking about.  There cant be multiple records with the same tmpl_id in the Template table, which the error indicates there is.  This means there is not a 1 to 1 relationship between the tables, it is a 1 to many.  This means it doesn't know which value to put in of the many values returned.

Comment: IF the tmpl_id values in the template table are all the same you can group the results.  But for this to work, they tmpl_id returned in all records must be the same.  Run the select query without the UPDATE and look at the tmpl IDs in the records and see if they vary.

Comment: i have run the select query it is showing correct result.

Comment: Then try the new one I posted with the GROUP By statement and see if it throws the same error.

Comment: Did you try the GROUP BY query?

Comment: Thanks once again sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update bsn_no
    set templ_id = (select t.templ_id
                    from template_table t
                    where t.obj_id = bsn_no.obj_id
                   );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database (although if you have duplicate `obj_id` in the `template_table`, it will return errors).  Specific databases have other syntax for combining tables in an `update`.

EDIT:

If this returns multiple rows, the simplest solution is an aggregation *without* `group by` or using `where rownum = 1`:

```
update bsn_no
    set templ_id = (select t.templ_id
                    from template_table t
                    where t.obj_id = bsn_no.obj_id and rownum = 1
                   );
```

This avoids the error, by choosing an (arbitrary) matching value.

Comment: it does not have any duplicate obj_id. it has duplicate temp_id.

Comment: if i run your query it has thrown the below error message.

SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: @user3040157 . . . It must have duplicate `obj_id` (which is the `join` key) if it is returning duplicate results.

Comment: With the rownum solution you MUST be positive about the duplicate data IDs, he was not.  The group solution would have still thrown an error instead of creating a bunch of bad data.  I considered TOP 1 in the sub query to accomplish the same thing but wasn't sure about his data, so went with the GROUP.  I was the +1 for explaining the duplicate key situation to him.

Comment: @VincentJames . . . I think you should explain that reasoning in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE BT
SET templ_ID = TT.templ_ID
FROM [Business Table] BT
INNER JOIN [Template Table] TT ON BT.obj_id = TT.obj_id
```