# Oracle SQL syntax error (missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax

I don't understand why this provokes a syntax error (missing right parenthesis):

```
UPDATE table
SET doc =
  (SELECT 'table-2844-doc' || SUBSTR(doc_file, INSTR(doc_file, '.', -1))
   FROM docvers
   WHERE (docvers.table_name = 'other_table'
          AND docvers.field_name = 'doc')
     AND ROWNUM = 1
   ORDER BY VERSION DESC)
WHERE table_id = 2844
```

This looks right to me, does get executed correctly in SQL Server, and is similar to requests found, for example, in [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table).

Any tip?

Comment: It probably doesn't do what you want (because it selects a single arbitrary row and then orders it -- which does nothing).  But I don't see an obvious syntax error.

Comment: It is syntax error. Scalar subquery block does not have ORDER BY in its syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET doc = (
 select r.myval
 from (
 SELECT 'table-2844-doc' || SUBSTR(doc_file, INSTR(doc_file, '.', -1)) myval, ROWNUM RN
 FROM docvers
 WHERE docvers.table_name = 'other_table'
 AND docvers.field_name = 'doc'
 ORDER BY VERSION DESC
 ) r
 where r.RN = 1
)
WHERE table_id = 2844
```

Select the data set first including the `ROWNUM`, then select from that data set the first row.

Comment: Weird that we have to make so many contorsions to be able to run a quite simple query. However, your solution stays quite clear, and does work. Thanks!