# Oracle how do I update a table with data from another table, using a join on multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update, multiple-tables

I have a bunch of tables that I need to link together with the goal of updating the name and address in the ub_gl_movement Table (relevant columns listed).

```
|ub_gl_movement|
:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
|UBGL_UBCT_CONTRACT_ID|UBGL_UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID|UBGL_PAYEE_NAME|ADDR_1     |ADDR_2|ADDR_3|SUBURB   |
:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
|194875               |000000Z0000480         |John Smith     |123 Some St|(null)|(null)|Somewhere|
```

The zz_person table is as follows

```
|zz_person|
:-------------------------------------------:
|ZZPD_PERSON_ID|ZZPD_FIRST_NAME|ZZPD_SURNAME|
:-------------------------------------------:
|21916908      |Bill           |Jones       |
```

The Address table is as follows

```
|ADDRESS|
:-----------------------------------------------------------:
|ZZAD_ZZPD_PERSON_ID|ZZAD_LINE_1    |ZZAD_LINE_2|ZZAD_LINE_3|
:-----------------------------------------------------------:
|21916908           |456 Main Street|(null)     |(null)     |
```

There's no way to link these tables as is, so I tried to link via another table called zz_investment_person using the INVESTMENT_ID and PERSON_ID.

EDIT: Adding DESC UB_INVESTMENT

```
DESC UTB.UB_INVESTMENT
Name                       Null     Type         
-------------------------- -------- ------------ 
UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(14) 
UBIN_DATE_FROM             NOT NULL DATE         
UBIN_DATE_TO               NOT NULL DATE         
UBIN_USER_LAST_UPD         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_DATE_LAST_UPD         NOT NULL DATE         
UBIN_UBTC_COUNTRY_CODE              VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_REF_TAX_INVEST_TYPE            VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_BAD_TAX_EXEMPTION_YN           VARCHAR2(1)  
UBIN_WITH_TAX_EXEMPTION_YN          VARCHAR2(1)  
UBIN_TFN_TAX_EXEMPTION_YN           VARCHAR2(1)  
UBIN_EXTERNAL_REF                   VARCHAR2(40) 
UBIN_REF_EXTRACT_MAIL               VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_VESTING_EXIST_YN               VARCHAR2(1)  
UBIN_REF_TAX_LEVEL                  VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_UBML_MARGIN_LENDER_ID          VARCHAR2(10) 
UBIN_REF_BUSINESS_TYPE              VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_REF_BUSINESS_DIVISION          VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_REF_SOURCE                     VARCHAR2(8)  
UBIN_CUSTOMER_REF_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(18) 

|zz_investment_person|
:--------------------------------------:
|ZZIP_INVESTMENT_ID|ZZIP_ZZPD_PERSON_ID|
:--------------------------------------:
|000000Z0000480    |21916908           |


DESC UTB.ZZ_INVESTMENT_PERSON

Name                     Null     Type         
------------------------ -------- ------------ 
ZZIP_INVESTMENT_ID       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(14) 
ZZIP_ZZPD_PERSON_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(8)    
ZZIP_REF_PERSON_RELN     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)  
ZZIP_DATE_FROM           NOT NULL DATE         
ZZIP_DATE_TO             NOT NULL DATE         
ZZIP_USER_LAST_UPD       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)  
ZZIP_DATE_LAST_UPD       NOT NULL DATE         
ZZIP_VEST_AGE                     NUMBER(2)    
ZZIP_DATE_VEST_EFFECTIVE          DATE         
ZZIP_DATE_VEST_PROCESSED          DATE
```

I need to update the ub_gl_movement table so that the UBGL_PAYEE_NAME is set to Bill Jones, with an address of 456 Main Street.  My query is

```
UPDATE 
(
  SELECT G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME PAYEE_NAME,
        P.ZZPD_FIRST_NAME F_NAME,
        P.ZZPD_SURNAME L_NAME
  FROM UTB.UB_GL_MOVEMENT G
  JOIN UTB.UB_INVESTMENT I
  ON G.UBGL_UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID = I.UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID
  JOIN UTB.ZZ_INVESTMENT_PERSON IP
  ON IP.ZZIP_INVESTMENT_ID = I.UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID
  JOIN UTB.ZZ_PERSON P 
  ON P.ZZPD_PERSON_ID = IP.ZZIP_ZZPD_PERSON_ID
  WHERE G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL
)
SET PAYEE_NAME = F_NAME || ' ' || L_NAME;
```

However I get the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

and if I run this query

```
UPDATE UTB.UB_GL_MOVEMENT G
SET G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME = 
(SELECT CASE WHEN (UPPER(ZZPD_REF_TITLE) = 'EST OF')
                    THEN SUBSTR(ZZPD_REF_TITLE, 1, 3) || ' ' || ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                  WHEN (ZZPD_REF_TITLE  IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_SURNAME IS NOT NULL ) 
                        THEN ZZPD_REF_TITLE || ' ' || ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                   WHEN (ZZPD_REF_TITLE IS NULL AND ZZPD_FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_SURNAME IS NOT NULL)
                        THEN ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                   ELSE 'SIR / MADAM' END
                  FROM UTB.ZZ_PERSON P
                  JOIN UTB.ZZ_INVESTMENT_PERSON IP 
                  ON P.ZZPD_PERSON_ID = IP.ZZIP_ZZPD_PERSON_ID
                  JOIN UTB.UB_INVESTMENT I
                  ON G.UBGL_UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID = I.UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID
                  AND ROWNUM = 1
                  )
WHERE G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

I get a different error

```
Error at Command Line:14 Column:21
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "G"."UBGL_UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I haven't updated the Address table in this query.  I figured I'll just start with the names first.

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT 2 - I have changed the second update query to

```
UPDATE UTB.UB_GL_MOVEMENT G
   SET G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME = (SELECT CASE WHEN (UPPER(ZZPD_REF_TITLE) = 'EST OF')
                                THEN SUBSTR(ZZPD_REF_TITLE, 1, 3) || ' ' || ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                              WHEN (ZZPD_REF_TITLE  IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_SURNAME IS NOT NULL ) 
                                    THEN ZZPD_REF_TITLE || ' ' || ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                               WHEN (ZZPD_REF_TITLE IS NULL AND ZZPD_FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND ZZPD_SURNAME IS NOT NULL)
                                    THEN ZZPD_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || ZZPD_SURNAME
                               ELSE 'SIR / MADAM' END
                    FROM UTB.ZZ_PERSON P
                    JOIN UTB.ZZ_INVESTMENT_PERSON IP ON P.ZZPD_PERSON_ID = IP.ZZIP_ZZPD_PERSON_ID
                    JOIN UTB.UB_INVESTMENT I ON I.UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID = IP.ZZIP_INVESTMENT_ID
                    JOIN UTB.UB_GL_MOVEMENT GMT ON GMT.UBGL_UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID = I.UBIN_INVESTMENT_ID
                    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
                   )
WHERE G.UBGL_PAYEE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

which does execute, but all PAYEE_NAMEs are the same, so it seems it has taken the first row from the ZZ_PERSON table and used that for all rows, instead of searching the table for the relevant ID / Name combination.  If I remove the rownum=1, I get an error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Comment: Please add a description of the UB_INVESTMENT table, as it's missing.

Comment: The error you receive in your second update statement is because you didn't use any table that it's alias is G.

Comment: Thanks @YaronIdan.  I have updated my question with the DESC of the table.  Hope that's enough.  I realised it may not be necessary to use it in the join.... but I'm not sure.

Comment: As for the missing alias, I have updated my query, but it appears that PAYEE_NAME is set to the first row of ZZ_PERSON.  This result is repeated for all rows in UB_GL_MOVEMENT.

Comment: Be very careful with Oracle updates. You basically need to put your constraints twice. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table