# SQL-ERROR: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

for the below sql-code i'am getting the following error:

> "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
update table_result s set (login, position, division, responsibility) = (
select distinct( u.login ), u.position, u.division, u.responsibility from table2 u
where s.user_name=u.login)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: subquery MUST return only one row for one user_name. field `login` in table2 must be unique or correct you subsquery for find only one row

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is clear.  You don't want `select distinct` in the subquery.  You want to be sure that it select one row.  For that purpose, use `rownum`:

```
update table_result s
    set (login, position, division, responsibility) =
             (select u.login, u.position, u.division, u.responsibility
              from table2 u
              where s.user_name = u.login and
                    rownum = 1
             );
```

Notes:

- `distinct` is not a function.  What are the parentheses for?  They suggest a misunderstanding.
- Using a subquery like this with `rownum = 1` suggests a logical flaw.  Which of the matching rows do you really want?

Comment: thank you, i tried to use that query also and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:
I don't think you can update multiple columns like this. One column to update and the subquery to return one value to update.

like this

```
update table_result s set login=(select distinct( u.login )from table2  
u where s.user_name=u.login)
```

I don't know why this is tagged as MySQL when it should be Oracle

Comment: Thanks, that works. The funny thing is that the query has worked before.

Comment: It happens :) Glad it helped you!!

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong syntax. You rather should be using a `MERGE` statement like below since in `Oracle` there is no such `update-join` construct available.

```
merge into table_result s 
using (
       select distinct  u.login , u.position, u.division, u.responsibility from table2 u
       join table_result s1 on s1.user_name = u.login) xxx
when matched then update
set s.login = xxx.login, 
s.position = xxx.position, 
s.division  = xxx.division, 
s.responsibility = xxx.responsibility;
```