# Updating Table Field SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables A and B

Table A like

```
paid_month    budget   amount

201703        11401    23000 
201703        11401    24000 
201703        11401    12000
```

---

Table B like

```
paid_month    budget   amount

201703        11402    23000 
201703        11403    24000 
201703        11404    12000
```

NOW i want to update The budget in table A as below

set `A.budget`=`B.budget` 
where `A.amount`=`B.amount`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Must it be the same month? Will there always be a matching record in B? Can there be more than one matching record in B?

Comment: yes it should be in same month

Comment: Wow, that already answers 33% of my questions. Why don't you answer the others?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Funny.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support an update-join syntax, but you can still achieve what you want using an update with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tableA a
SET budget = (SELECT b.budget FROM tableB b
              WHERE a.amount = b.amount AND a.paid_month = b.paid_month)
```