# Update table from another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables in Database first is the following :
First Table is EMPSHIFT

```
EmployeeID   01/04/2017   02/04/2017    03/04/2017   04/04/2017   to  30/04/2017
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              7,6
2
3
4

to end of all employees
```

second table is SCHEDULEEMPLOYEES

```
EmployeeID    DayDate           Shift
------------------------------------
1            01/04/2017          7,6
1            02/04/2017          5,2
1            03/04/2017          7,6
1            04/04/2017          9
2            01/04/2017          9
2            02/04/2017          3,2
3            01/04/2017          7,6
3            03/04/2017          9

to the end of table data
```

I want make PL-SQL stored procedure or SQL statement  to update the first table data from the second as to set the shift data in the specific column date like for 
EmployeeID = 1 his shift in 01/04/2017 = 7,6

what i have tried till now is the following 
[What I tried till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ38c.png)

but doesn't work can any help in this

Comment: Can you please post your code here for review. Links are not accessible to all.

Comment: You apply updates using the [`UPDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm) or [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm) statements. What isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use MERGE statement as below:

```
DECLARE
  l_date DATE:=TO_DATE('01/04/2017','DD/MM/YYYY');
BEGIN
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'MERGE INTO EMPSHIFT E
USING SCHEDULEEMPLOYEES S
ON (S.EMPLOYEEID=E.EMPLOYEEID AND S.DAYDATE=TO_DATE('''||TO_CHAR(l_date)||''',''DD/MM/YYYY''))
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET E."'||TO_CHAR(l_date)||'"=S.SHIFT';
    l_date:=l_date+1;
    EXIT
  WHEN l_date>TO_DATE('30/04/2017','DD/MM/YYYY');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You mentioned that you want to update records, but if you would like to insert missing records (for missing EMPLOYEEID in EMPSHIFT table), please refer to [merge_insert_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#i2090698)

Answer (score 0):

or you talking about pivot/unpivot (it's exist in Oracle 11g)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DayDate,
               EmployeeID,
               SUM(Shift) shift
          FROM SCHEDULEEMPLOYEES
         GROUP BY DayDate,
                  EmployeeID)
PIVOT(SUM(shift)
   FOR DayDate IN(to_date('01/04/2017',
                          'mm/dd/yyyy'),
                  to_date('02/04/2017',
                          'mm/dd/yyyy'),
                  to_date('03/04/2017',
                          'mm/dd/yyyy'),
                  to_date('04/04/2017',
                          'mm/dd/yyyy')));
```