# How can I combine 2 joins in an update?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

The code below (currently with error) would update all rows in the table, but I'm aiming for that the code should only update the `p.hour` of the `per_id` in the where clause and not all rows.

It's important that the value for the set is a column form table worker and one from table department

```
update worker
set p_hour = p_hour + a.hour
where exists
(select
p.per_id,
p.p_hour
from
worker p,
department a
where
p.per_id = a.per_id and
p.per_id = '1234')
```

This is my current error:

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-00904: "a.hour": invalid identifier

Comment: you can't reference a table in `set` from the `where` clause see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031405/1398418 for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way in Oracle is:

```
update worker w
    set p_hour = (p_hour +
                  (select d.hour
                   from department d
                   where w.per_id = d.per_id
                  )
                 )
    where w.per_id = '1234' and
          exists (select 1
                  from department d
                  where w.per_id = d.per_id
                 );
```

You can also use `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an updateable join view, inline or otherwise:

```
update (
         select e.employee_id, e.salary, d.department_name
         from   employees e
                join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
       )
set    salary = salary * 10
where  department_name = 'Finance';
```

For this to be allowed, the view has to be key-preserved. In this example, we can update employees because departments.department_id has a unique key or index.