# Update multiple columns using values from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's an example.

[image]

I want to update Table1 where Address IS NULL to the format State: Zip in 1 single update statement as this table probably has 10k rows. In Oracle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table

Comment: Thanks guys. I resolved my problem using the last solution in the link Kamil posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
For i in (select id, name, zip from table2) 
LOOP
Update table1 set address = state ||': '|| i.zip where id = i.id and 
address is null;
END LOOP;
END;
```