# Can I make an update using also a FROM statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I would like to make an `UPDATE` on some fields of a table including also a `FROM` condition like in the following:

```
UPDATE T_NEW_TABLE_IMPORT_STATUS TB
SET
    ID = NULL,
    IMPORT_DATE = NULL,
    IMPORT_STATUS = 0,
    ERROR_CODE = 3,
    LASTMODIFIEDAT = NULL
FROM T_BEDA
WHERE 1=1
    AND TB.TRANSACTION_ID = 999
    AND TB.TRANSACTION_ID = T_BEDA.TAC
    AND T_BEDA.SOP IS NULL;
```

In the current status it fails with the following error:

> Error report - 
>   SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Apparently the `FROM` clause is not allowed in this case.

Basically, I would like this update to take place only when the `T_BEDA.SOP` is `NULL`.  How can I solve this using SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: See [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: You have to join T_BEDA & T_NEW_TABLE_IMPORT_STATUS in the FROM clause

Comment: @VenkataramanR No, Oracle does not support such update join syntax.  Well, maybe, if you count updating an inline view, but you never said that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Sorry. I am from MSSQL World.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` clause to check if the `TRANSACTION_ID` exists in `T_BEDA`:

```
UPDATE T_NEW_TABLE_IMPORT_STATUS TB
SET ID = NULL,
    IMPORT_DATE = NULL,
    IMPORT_STATUS = 0,
    ERROR_CODE = 3,
    LASTMODIFIEDAT = NULL
WHERE TB.TRANSACTION_ID = 999 
  AND TB.TRANSACTION_ID IN (
        SELECT T_BEDA.TAC 
        FROM T_BEDA 
        WHERE TB.TRANSACTION_ID = T_BEDA.TAC
          AND T_BEDA.SOP IS NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use Postgres update syntax.  Oracle does not support this, nor does it support update joins, but you may rephrase your update to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to inspect the second table:

```
UPDATE T_NEW_TABLE_IMPORT_STATUS TB
SET ID = NULL,
    IMPORT_DATE = NULL,
    IMPORT_STATUS = 0,
    ERROR_CODE = 3,
    LASTMODIFIEDAT = NULL
WHERE
    TB.TRANSACTION_ID = 999 AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_BEDA t WHERE TB.TRANSACTION_ID = t.TAC AND t.SOP IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do:

```
UPDATE T_NEW_TABLE_IMPORT_STATUS TB
 SET ID = NULL,IMPORT_DATE = NULL,IMPORT_STATUS = 0,ERROR_CODE = 3, LASTMODIFIED = NULL 
WHERE 
 (TB.TRANSACTION_ID = 999) AND 
 (TB.TRANSACTION_ID) = (Select T_BEDA.TAC From T_BEDA WHERE T_BEDA.SOP           IS NULL)
```