# Update date field of one table from the value taken from another table

Tags: sql, date, join, oracle11g, sql-update

I have two table A and B where both have date fields but in different format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS' and 'MM/DD/YYYY') and they both have a common field called invoiced_value. I need to update the date values of table A(with 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') from the values of table B(with 'MM/DD/YYYY'). Can i use the following query?. can i append the date like this to_date(e.invoiced_date ||' 3:56:24', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') ?.

```
  UPDATE Table1
  SET m.invoiced_date = to_date(e.invoiced_date ||' 3:56:24', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
  FROM Table2 e, Table1 m
  WHERE m.invoiced_value = e.invoiced_value
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Your date format model isn't correct - how do you get times that are >= midday in? You need either `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` or `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM`, with the data passed in appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 dst
USING Table2 src
ON ( src.invoiced_value = dst.invoiced_value )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET invoiced_date = TRUNC( src.invoiced_date ) + INTERVAL '3:56:24' HOUR TO SECOND;
```

---

> Can i use the following query?

No, an [`UPDATE` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm) does not have a `FROM` clause. You would need to use a correlated sub-query or a `MERGE` statement.

> can i append the date like this `to_date(e.invoiced_date ||' 3:56:24', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')` ?.

Maybe ... but you should not do it this way. `TO_DATE( string_value, format_model )` takes a string as the first argument (and the `||` string concatenation operator also requires string arguments to concatenate) so your `e.invoiced_date` will be implicitly converted from a `DATE` to a string and your expression is effectively:

```
to_date(
  TO_CHAR(
    e.invoiced_date,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ) || ' 3:56:24',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'
)
```

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is `MM/DD/YYYY` then your query will work. If it is something different then your query will either raise an exception or work but give incorrect results. Since `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter and each user can set it to whatever value they want then you should not rely on this to be consistent.

Instead, add an interval literal to the date (which does not require any conversions to-or-from a string):

```
TRUNC( src.invoiced_date ) + INTERVAL '3:56:24' HOUR TO SECOND
```

Or explicitly convert the date to a string in the correct format:

```
TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( e.invoiced_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) || ' 3:56:24', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer