# Updating a table in Oracle by inner query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I have the following query, which works in Sybase, and I need help to rewrite it for Oracle.
I am new to Oracle.

```
update table1 
set col1 = (select sum(col3) from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col <> 'on')
from table1 t1 
where t1.id > 1 and t1.col5 in (12,13) and exists 
(select id from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col <> 'on' and col3 > 0)
```

When I tried to execute in Oracle I am getting missing expression error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql-update+join

Comment: Looking at the query, If you just remove the `from table1 t1 ` and add alias to update clause like `update table1 t1` should work

Comment: @sujai, does it make sense to put it as an answer ? You can do so and accept your own answer.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684910/error-in-oracle-query-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row/63685084#63685084

Comment: @sujai: I answered and try to explain. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 update table1 t1
 set t1.col1 = (select sum(col3) from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col <> 'on')
 where t1.id > 1 and t1.col5 in (12,13) and exists 
 (select id from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col <> 'on' and col3 > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can't use From clause like this:

There are three options in Oracle to update table based on another table:

Update it as an updateview

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.id, 
               t1.name name1,
               t1.desc desc1,
               t2.name name2,
               t2.desc desc2
          FROM table1 t1,
               table2 t2
         WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
   SET name1 = name2,
       desc1 = desc2
```

Update by wrting a subquery i.e. correlared update

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT t2.name, t2.desc
                         FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id )
```

Update using Merge statement without insert:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING
(
-- For more complicated queries you can use WITH clause here
SELECT * FROM table2
)t2
ON(t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
t1.name = t2.name,
t1.desc = t2.desc;
```

Below is the Oracle official update [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm)

Above examples are taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: When I tried Update by wrting a subquery i.e. correlared update, its keep on executing

Comment: Could you please update your question with correlated query and explain the logic and if possible share some sample data.