# Error in oracle query Single row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

Any Idea what is the problem here ? How to convert the below Sybase query to Oracle.

Sybase query

```
Update student  s1 set s1.delay = (select  date1 - date2 from cource c where c.ID = c1.ID and 
c.value  ='On' and c.Act_id = 
select max(Act_id) from cource c2 where c2.Id = C.id and c2.value ='On')
from student s1, Cource c1
where c1.id = s1.id and 
c1.value ='On' and 
s1.status = 'active' and 
s1.currentprofile = s1.prevProfile
```

After converting the above query to oracle I am getting this error "Single row sub query returns more than one row"

```
Update student  s1 set s1.delay = (select (select  date1 - date2 from cource c where c.ID = c1.ID and             
c.value  ='On' and c.Act_id = 
select max(Act_id) from cource c2 where c2.Id = C.id and c2.value ='On')
from student s1, Cource c1
where c1.id = s1.id and 
c1.value ='On' and 
s1.status = 'active' and 
s1.currentprofile = s1.prevProfile)
Where Exists
(select (select  date1 - date2 from cource c where c.ID = c1.ID and c.value  ='On' and c.Act_id = 
select max(Act_id) from cource c2 where c2.Id = C.id and c2.value ='On')
from student s1, Cource c1
where c1.id = s1.id and 
c1.value ='On' and 
s1.status = 'active' and 
s1.currentprofile = s1.prevProfile)
```

Comment: By the way, `cource` should probably be `course`.

Comment: @William Robertson: You are right and the reason I didn't emphasize on it as it was not sure for me the scope of the changes interms of renaming.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sybase query(for explain purpose):**

```
update student s1 
   set s1.delay = 
   (select (date1 -date2) 
      from cource c 
     where ****c.id = c1.id****(II)
       and c.value  ='On' 
       and c.Act_id = select max(Act_id) 
                        from cource c2 
                       where c2.Id = C.id 
                         and c2.value ='On')
  ****from student s1
     , cource c1****(I)
 where c1.id = s1.id 
   and c1.value ='On' 
   and s1.status = 'active' 
   and s1.currentprofile = s1.prevProfile;
```

While updating there are two main conditions we can see,

1. First, if you see the part `****from student s1 , cource c1****(I)` this one makes sure you are only updating the rows from `student` table which has matching `id` in `cource` table along with some more conditions, AND because Oracle don't allow such type of checks directly in the `from` clause of the `update` statement, it can be replaced with `exists` clause which can be seen in the below Oracle query.
2. Second, the part `****c.id = c1.id****(II)` in above Sybase query makes sure it further only fetch the data for the `set` clause by `co-relate` to the `ids` we found in the first step and for Oracle this we need to replace with the actual table which is being updated i.e. `student` because we already make sure with `exists` in the first step what `ids` has to be updated.

***Oracle Query(actual query):***

```
update student s1 
   set s1.delay = (select (date1 - date2)
                     from cource c 
                    where c.id = s1.id 
                      and c.value  ='On' 
                      and c.act_id = select max(act_id) 
                                       from cource c2 
                                      where c2.Id = c.id 
                                        and c2.value ='On')
from student s1
where s1.status = 'active' 
  and s1.currentprofile = s1.prevprofile
  and exists (select 1 
                from cource c1
               where c1.id = s1.id 
                 and c1.value ='On');
```

Comment: I have tried. Can you help on this resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775974/query-returning-ora-01427-single-row-subquery-returning-more-than-one-row

Comment: @sujai , I was already checking will take some time to answer but I don't understand the part where it does the `sysdate - pd.exittime` which is part of else clause of condition `pd.exittime != null` ..... does it make sense to do `sysdate - null` ? the result will be null only

Comment: it is typo mistake. I have asked to updated the question

Comment: @sujai, I answered there but don't know whether it worked or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use key presered view to update using this query. Oracle does not allow From clause in Update query Or use Correlated update or Merge with update only.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Correlated update:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT t2.name, t2.desc
                         FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id )
```