# Error while executing the below Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, subquery

I was trying convert below Sybase query to Oracle query.

```
update Student set st.age = (case when st.promoted != 'fail' then 1 
else (select sc1.age from school sc1 where st.id = sc1.id ) END)
from Student st ,School sc
where st.id = sc.id
AND st.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND st.currentClass = sc.currentClass 
AND st.currentCource = sc.currentCource ;
```

But I have tried executing below Oracle query after conversion but getting following error.

```
update Student st set st.age = (select (case when st.promoted != 'fail' 
then 1 
else (select sc1.age from school sc1 where st.id = sc1.id ) END) 
from School sc   
where st.id = sc.id
AND st.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND st.currentClass = sc.currentClass 
AND st.currentCource = sc.currentCource )
where exists 
   (select 1 from School sc1
where st.id = sc1.id
AND st.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND st.currentClass = sc1.currentClass 
AND st.currentCource = sc1.currentCource);
```

Query returning : ORA-01427 Single-row subquery returning more than one row. Any one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update Student st set st.age = case when st.promoted != 'fail'
                                    then 1 
                                    else (select sc1.age from school sc1
                                          where st.id = sc1.id )
                                    end
where exists 
   (select 1 from School sc1
where st.id = sc1.id
AND st.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND st.currentClass = sc1.currentClass 
AND st.currentCource = sc1.currentCource);
```

Comment: I have updated 20 with case statement , how to convert now

Comment: I have tried the same way this sybase query to convert but not working: Can you help me `update Product set pd.age = (case when pd.exittime!= null then 1 else ( case when pd.queue = dp.queue then (select (sysdate - pd.exittime) from department dp1 where pd.id = dp1.id ) else 2 END) END) from Product pd,department dp where pd.id > 1 AND pd.id = dp.id AND pd.status in('1','7','2','5') AND pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus AND pd.activity= dp.activity;`

Comment: You need to specify the alias: `update Product pd set...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221085/discussion-between-saloni-and-tony-andrews).

Comment: You are still trying to update with a join in the new query - you haven't converted it.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support `join`s in `update` statements. You can use a correlated subquery instead - all the join does is filtering, so `exists` should do it:

```
update student st 
set st.age = 20 
where 
    st.status in(1, 7, 2, 5)
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from school sc 
        where 
            st.id = sc.id  
            and st.currentClass = sc.currentClass  
            and st.currentCource = sc.currentCource 
    )
```

Comment: Updated the value with case statement , now any change required on your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key preserved view to write this update as below:

```
UPDATE (SELECT st.age as age, 
                st.promoted,
                sc.age,
               st.currentClass,
               sc.currentClass,
               st.currentCource,
               sc.currentCource
          FROM Student st INNER JOIN
               School sc
         ON (st.id = sc.id AND st.currentClass = sc.currentClass AND st.currentCource = sc.currentCource)
         WHERE st.status IN ('1','7','2','5'))
   SET age = CASE WHEN st.promoted != 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE sc.age END;
```

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684910/error-in-oracle-query-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row/63685084#63685084)
where I have responded how can Sybase update query can be converted to Oracle.