# Query returning : ORA-01427 Single-row subquery returning more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I was trying convert below Sybase query to Oracle query.

```
update Product set pd.age = (case when pd.exittime!= null then (sysdate - 
pd.exittime)  
else ( case when pd.queue = dp.queue 
then (select (sysdate - pd.entrytime) from department dp1 where pd.id = 
dp1.id ) else 2 END) END)
from Product pd,department dp
where pd.id > 1
AND pd.id = dp.id
AND pd.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus 
AND pd.activity= dp.activity;
```

But I have tried executing below Oracle query after conversion but getting following error.

```
update Product pd set pd.age = (select (case when pd.exittime!= null then 
(sysdate - pd.exittime)   
else ( case when pd.queue = dp.queue 
then (select (sysdate - pd.entrytime) from department dp1 where pd.id = dp1.id 
 ) else 2 END) END)
from department dp
where pd.id > 1
AND pd.id = dp.id
AND pd.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus 
AND pd.activity= dp.activity) 
where exists 
(select 1 from department dp
where pd.id > 1
AND pd.id = dp.id
AND pd.status in('1','7','2','5')
AND pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus 
AND pd.activity= dp.activity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with below,

I have used `coalesce` in case there is no match for column `queue` it will consider it as null and value `2` is taken instead.

```
update product pd
set    pd.age = case
                   when pd.exittime != null then
                    (sysdate - pd.exittime)
                   else
                    coalesce((select (sysdate - pd.entrytime)
                                from department dp
                                where pd.queue = dp.queue
                                  and pd.id = dp.id)
                            ,2)
                end
where  pd.id > 1
and    pd.status in ('1','7','2','5')
and    exists (select 1
                 from department dp
                where pd.id = dp.id
                  and pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus
                  and pd.activity = dp.activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in earlier answer please use key preserved view to convert such type of Sybase update queries to Oracle, as Oracle dont allow JOINs in update queries.

```
UPDATE (SELECT pd.age as age,
              pd.id,
              dp.id,
              pd.currentstatus,
              dp.currentstatus,
              pd.activity,
              dp.activity,
              pd.status,
              pd.exittime,
              pd.queue,
              dp.queue
              FROM Product pd INNER JOIN department dp
        ON (pd.id = dp.id AND pd.currentstatus = dp.currentstatus AND pd.activity= dp.activity)
        WHERE pd.id > 1 AND pd.status in('1','7','2','5'))
SET pd.age = CASE WHEN pd.exittime!= null THEN 1 
ELSE ( CASE WHEN pd.queue = dp.queue 
            THEN sysdate - pd.exittime
            ELSE 2 END) 
    END;
```