# Oracle Merge - unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: oracle, merge

I have a table `Library`

```
BranchNo BookShelfNo BookId BookSupplerNo

1234      4545        666     

1234      4546        667

1234      4547        668  

1234      4550        668
```

Table : `BookSupplier`

```
BookNo  SupplierNo      

666       9112
667       9897
667       9998
668       9545
```

I need to write an update statement where first I have to supply only the list of bookshelf, and the update query should find out

- The `BookId` for that `BookShelfNo` in the `Library Table`.
- Find `SupplierNo` in for that Book in the `BookSupplier Table`.
- Update `BookSupplierNo` in the `Library table`.

Note : `BookShelfNo` is unique.
A `BookId` can have multiple `SupplierNo` and we can use any number

I had written something like this from [Oracle SQL: Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/oracle-sql-update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

```
MERGE INTO Library lib
USING
(
SELECT BookNo, SupplierNo FROM BookSupplier
)bs
ON(lib.BookId = bs.BookNo)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
lib.BOOKSUPPLERNO = bs.SupplierNo
where lib.BookShelfNo in ('4545','4546')
```

It says,

```
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

I know it is because I have duplicates in BookSupplier column, but then I added distinct like this

```
MERGE INTO Library lib
USING
(
SELECT distinct BookNo, SupplierNo FROM BookSupplier
)bs
ON(lib.BookId = bs.BookNo)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
lib.BOOKSUPPLERNO = bs.SupplierNo
where lib.BookShelfNo in ('4545','4546')
```

Now , it says

```
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnosis is correct, but the cure you tried makes no sense. The pairs `(bookno, supplierno)` are already distinct - what did you expect adding `DISTINCT` to do there?

Rather, the subquery should somehow get only one row (one single `supplierno`) for each `bookno`. For example:

```
......
using
(select bookno, max(supplierno) as supplierno from booksupplier group by bookno) bs
......
```