# Need to update a table based on the data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a complex update where I need to update the data in one table based on the output from another table.

Scenario:

Table 1: HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS (FK PARTY_ID FROM HZ_PARTIES)

| PARTY_ID | CUST_ACCOUNT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 567 |

Table 2 HZ_PARTIES

| PARTY_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | XYZ |

Table 3 HZ_CONTACT_POINTS (FK PARTY_ID FROM HZ_PARTIES)

| OWNER_TABLE_ID | EMAIL | OWNER_TABLE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | XYZ@GMAIL | HZ_PARTIES |
| 123 | ABC@GMAIL | HZ_PARTY_SITES |

Table 4: Customer_dimension_table

| cust_account_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 567 | 879 |

Table 5: Contact_dimension_table(target table)

| customer_id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 879 | XYZ | NULL |
| 999 | XYZ | NULL |
| 879 | ABC | NULL |

I need your expertise in filling up the email address for the XYZ based on the above source table.
Is this transformation possible?
I am trying to fetch the contacts in oracle ebs but in the main query it is giving me the wrong email address for some of the parties as some of the parties have party_id(hz_parties) matching with the party_site_id(in HZ_party_sites). Hence I wanted to make an update so that it can update the correct email_address but update approach seems not to be working.

Here is the problematic query:

```
SELECT hcar.cust_account_role_id,        
                hcar.current_role_state,
                hcar.role_type,
                hcar.status,
                hcar.cust_account_id,
                hcar.cust_acct_site_id/* , ( SELECT hp.party_name
                                             FROM hz_parties hp
                                             WHERE 1=1
                                               AND hp.party_id = hcar.party_id
                                         ) contact_name */
                                      
                ,
                (SELECT hp.party_name
                   FROM hz_parties hp, hz_relationships hr
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hr.party_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hp.party_id = hr.object_id
                        AND hr.object_type = 'PERSON'
                        AND hr.relationship_code IN
                               ('CONTACT', 'EMPLOYER_OF'))
                   contact_name,
                hcp.contact_point_id,
                hcp.phone_country_code,
                NVL(hcp.phone_area_code, (SELECT hcp.phone_area_code
                   FROM hz_contact_points hcp
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hcp.owner_table_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hcp.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                        AND hcp.phone_area_code IS NOT NULL     
                        --AND hcp.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'            
                        AND hcp.contact_point_id =
                               (SELECT MAX (hcp2.contact_point_id)
                                  FROM hz_contact_points hcp2
                                 WHERE     1 = 1
                                       AND hcp2.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                                       AND hcp2.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'
                                       AND hcp2.owner_table_id =
                                              hcp.owner_table_id))) phone_area_code, 
                NVL(hcp.phone_number, (SELECT hcp.phone_number
                   FROM hz_contact_points hcp
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hcp.owner_table_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hcp.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                        --AND hcp.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'             
                        AND hcp.phone_number IS NOT NULL              
                        AND hcp.contact_point_id =
                               (SELECT MAX (hcp2.contact_point_id)
                                  FROM hz_contact_points hcp2
                                 WHERE     1 = 1
                                       AND hcp2.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                                       --AND hcp2.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'
                                       AND hcp2.owner_table_id =
                                              hcp.owner_table_id))) phone_number, 
                NVL(hcp.phone_extension, (SELECT hcp.phone_extension
                   FROM hz_contact_points hcp
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hcp.owner_table_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hcp.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                       -- AND hcp.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'
                        AND hcp.phone_extension  IS NOT NULL
                        AND hcp.contact_point_id =
                               (SELECT MAX (hcp2.contact_point_id)
                                  FROM hz_contact_points hcp2
                                 WHERE     1 = 1
                                       AND hcp2.phone_line_type(+) = 'GEN'
                                       --AND hcp2.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'
                                       AND hcp2.owner_table_id =
                                              hcp.owner_table_id))) phone_extension , 
               NVL(hcp.email_address, 
                        NVL(( SELECT  MAX(SUBSTR (hcp.email_address, 1, 50))
                                           FROM hz_contact_points hcp
                                          WHERE     1 = 1
                                                AND hcp.owner_table_id IN (SELECT hr3.party_id
                                                                            FROM hz_parties hp3, 
                                                                                hz_relationships hr3,
                                                                                hz_cust_account_roles hcar3
                                                                      WHERE     1 = 1
                                                                           AND hr3.party_id = hcar3.party_id
                                                                            AND hp3.party_id = hr3.object_id
                                                                            AND hr3.object_type = 'PERSON'
                                                                            AND hr3.relationship_code IN
                                                                                   ('CONTACT', 'EMPLOYER_OF')
                                                                            and hcar.cust_account_id=hcar3.cust_account_id
                                                                            and hp3.party_name = (SELECT hp1.party_name
                                                                                   FROM hz_parties hp1, hz_relationships hr1
                                                                                  WHERE     1 = 1
                                                                                        AND hr1.party_id= hcar.party_id
                                                                                        AND hp1.party_id = hr1.object_id
                                                                                        AND hr1.object_type = 'PERSON'
                                                                                        AND hr1.relationship_code IN
                                                                                               ('CONTACT', 'EMPLOYER_OF')) )
                                                --= hcar.party_id
                                                AND hcp.contact_point_type = 'EMAIL'
                                                AND hcp.email_address IS NOT NULL  
                                                 ),
                        ( (SELECT hp.email_address
                                           FROM hz_parties hp 
                                          WHERE     1 = 1 
                                                AND hp.party_id = hcar.party_id ))
                        )
                        ) email_address, 
                (SELECT DECODE (hcp2.contact_point_type,
                                'TLX', hcp2.telex_number,
                                hcp2.phone_number)
                   FROM hz_contact_points hcp2, fnd_lookup_values flv
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hcp2.contact_point_id = hcp.contact_point_id
                        AND hcp2.contact_point_type NOT IN ('EDI')
                        AND hcp2.owner_table_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hcp2.primary_flag = 'Y'
                        AND NVL (hcp2.phone_line_type,
                                 hcp2.contact_point_type) = 'FAX'
                        AND NVL (hcp2.phone_line_type,
                                 hcp2.contact_point_type) = flv.lookup_code
                        AND (   (    flv.lookup_type = 'COMMUNICATION_TYPE'
                                 AND flv.lookup_code IN
                                        ('PHONE', 'TLX', 'EMAIL', 'WEB'))
                             OR (flv.lookup_type = 'PHONE_LINE_TYPE'))
                        AND flv.language = USERENV ('LANG')
                        AND flv.view_application_id = 222
                        AND flv.security_group_id = 0)
                   fax,
                (SELECT SUBSTR (NVL (hoc.job_title, hoc.job_title_code),
                                1,
                                250)
                   FROM hz_org_contacts hoc, hz_relationships hr
                  WHERE     1 = 1
                        AND hoc.party_relationship_id = hr.relationship_id
                        AND hr.party_id = hcar.party_id
                        AND hr.object_type = 'ORGANIZATION'
                        AND hr.directional_flag = 'F')
                   job_title,
                'ORACLE' data_source,
                hcp.primary_flag                     
           FROM hz_cust_account_roles hcar, hz_contact_points hcp
          WHERE     1 = 1
                -- AND hcar.current_role_state = 'A'
                AND hcp.owner_table_id(+) = hcar.party_id
                AND hcp.primary_flag(+) = 'Y'
                AND hcar.party_id IN
                       (SELECT hr.party_id
                          FROM hz_org_contacts hoc, hz_relationships hr
                         WHERE     1 = 1
                               AND hoc.party_relationship_id =
                                      hr.relationship_id
                               AND hr.object_type = 'ORGANIZATION'
                               AND hr.directional_flag = 'F'
                               AND hoc.last_update_date > SYSDATE -5    
                        UNION
                        SELECT party_id
                          FROM hz_cust_account_roles
                         WHERE last_update_date > SYSDATE - 5       
                         )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: Sorry, No this is not helping me

Comment: You've missed *"... because <reasoning>"*. Otherwise it is hard to provide a solution that does meet your (implicit) criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```sql
UPDATE Contact_dimension_table cont
SET email = ( SELECT p.email
              FROM   Customer_dimension_table cust
                     INNER JOIN HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS a
                     ON cust.cust_account_id = a.customer_account_id
                     INNER JOIN HZ_CONTACT_POINTS p
                     ON a.party_id = p.party_id
              WHERE  p.owner_table = 'HZ_PARTIES'
              AND    cont.customer_id = cust.customer_id
            );
```

You may need to also include `HZ_PARTIES` if you need to match on the name as well as the `customer_id`.

```sql
UPDATE Contact_dimension_table cont
SET email = ( SELECT p.email
              FROM   Customer_dimension_table cust
                     INNER JOIN HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS a
                     ON cust.cust_account_id = a.customer_account_id
                     INNER JOIN HZ_CONTACT_POINTS cp
                     ON a.party_id = cp.party_id
                     INNER JOIN HZ_PARTIES p
                     ON a.party_id = p.party_id
              WHERE  cp.owner_table = 'HZ_PARTIES'
              AND    cont.customer_id = cust.customer_id
              AND    cont.name = p.name
            );
```

Comment: Thank You Boss! Need to match with the name also as in  Contact_dimension_table(target table) we have same name for different customer_id and for the customer_id that we need to make changes multiple records are there. Can you please help.

Comment: Hi, I have ran the query but it is giving me error as single row subquery returns more than one row. Actually I am trying to fetch the contacts in oracle ebs but in the main query it is giving me the wrong email address for some of the parties as some of the parties have party_id(hz_parties) matching with the party_site_id(in HZ_party_sites). Hence I wanted to make an update so that it can update the correct email_address but update approach seems not to be working.