# Update table 1 with data from table 2 in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good afternoon colleagues, I have a problem with a query to update data with information from another table.

```
UPDATE TPR
SET TPR.doxa = result.doxa 
FROM TABLA1 TPR 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.S, t1.D) AS doxa
    FROM TABLA1 t1 
    INNER JOIN TABLA2 t2 ON t1.S = t2.D 
) result ON c.S = result.S
WHERE TPR.S = result.S;
```

Error starting at line: 18 of the command -

```
UPDATE TPR
SET TPR.doxa = result.doxa
FROM TABLE1 TPR
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.S, t1.D) AS doxa
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.S = t2.D
) result ON c.S = result.S
WHERE TPR.S = result.S
```

```
Command line error: 20 Column: 1
Bug Report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not completed correctly
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

Could someone help me on what I'm doing wrong or if there is another way?

Comment: You are not using standard SQL syntax as supported by Oracle, but some propriatary syntax (SQL Server maybe?). I was about to write an answer, but I don't understand your update statement. You seem to update t1.doxa with t1.d, but somehow t2 comes into play. There is also a parenthesis too many or too few in your query, which makes it even harder to understand. Can you please describe what excatly you want to update with what other value under which condition?

Comment: What I want to update is the doxa of table1 with the information of the doxa of table2 and the condition is the S (AGE) that it obtains from the select and compares the age of table 1 and the result of the select

Comment: Okay. You want to update t1.doxa with t2.doxa. (t2.doxa is not in your statement btw.) You expect to find exactly one row per age in t2. It is probably the primary key. Yes? So for every row in t1 you look for a row of the same age in t2 that you will use for the update. The age in t1 is called s, and the age in t2 is called d. Yes? Will there be an entry for every age in t2 or can there be t1 rows with an age that are not in t2? If there can be missing ages, what do you want to do with those t1 rows? Leave the doxa as is or set it to null?

Comment: What I want is to update the information that t2 contains in t1 doxa is a column that the two tables contain
I upload a file that is where the information from t2 comes, which is a temporary table and I compare it with what comes in t1 and if the age matches in the 2 and the doxa information is changed, I want it to be updated

Comment: Which doesn't answer the questions. **1.** There is only one row per age in t2. Yes? **2.** Does each age that occur in t1 also occur in t2? **3.** If the last answer was no, then what to do with t1 that don't have a match? Leave the doxa as is or set it to null? **4.** The doxa column in t2 is named doxa, and that it doesn't appear in your statement was a typo. Yes? **5.** The age column in t1 is named s? **6.** The age column in t2 is named d?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a table with data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030699/update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table)

Comment: And there are hundreds of the same questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+update+table+from+another+table

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch to `merge`:

```
merge into tpr
using (select t1.s, 
              t1.d as doxa
       from tabla1 t1 join tabla2 t2 on t1.s = t2.d
      ) result
on (result.s = tpr.s)
when matched then update set
  tpr.doxa = result.doxa;
```

Comment: But I don't need to use the merge but only this query, I send this query to a cursor

Comment: Sure you don't *need to*, but you *could* - especially if *your* option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE ... FROM ...` is not valid Oracle syntax. Even if it was, your query is not valid as you have one opening `(` bracket and two closing `)` brackets and you use an alias `c` that is never defined anywhere.

You can rewrite your query to valid Oracle syntax as:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 dst
SET   doxa = d
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM   table2 t2
              WHERE  dst.S = t2.D );
```

If you are expecting to update the value to the `D` column value from `table2` (which is **NOT** what your query is actually doing, it is updating the value to the `D` column value from `table1`) then use a sub-query in the `SET` clause:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 dst
SET   doxa = (SELECT t2.d
              FROM   table2 t2
              WHERE  dst.S = t2.D )
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM   table2 t2
              WHERE  dst.S = t2.D );
```

or, since `table1.s = table2.d` you can simplify it to:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 dst
SET   doxa = s
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
              FROM   table2 t2
              WHERE  dst.S = t2.D );
```

or:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING table2 src
ON (src.d = dst.s)
SET   doxa = src.d;
```

*(All of these options only work if there will always be a single row match between `table1` and `table2`.)*